# Print from CSV file, row by row

Tags: windows, printing, csv

I have a CSV file. I need to print this file row by row.

For example, each row contains name, surname, email, profession and so on, many columns. First row contains the column titles. I would like to print each row on one page. Each data should print like this:

```
Name: John
Surname: Doe
Email: john@doe.com
```

etc, where Name and Surname and Email column names come from the CSV's first row.

Now I'd need to print, let's say 100 rows like this, automatically, from the CSV file. How can I achieve that? I could also do a little programming if necessary.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic for SU. So I should not recommend open office's `calc`. :)

Comment: Well, I'd say this is a specific enough question so as not to become not constructive. I reworded it a little. It doesn't really need to be closed.

Comment: Open the file in a spreadsheet program (Open Source ones are available) make sure it's lined up like you want, and print it.  Another idea is to import the CSV into an open source SQL (like PostgreSQL) and the use PHP and JavaScript to format it/pint it.

Comment: Actually, I've created this question after being unable to do it with Calc. At least, nothing like this in menu. Again, I need one record (=1 row) per page, vertically (as specified above). As for using PHP and SQL: yes, perhaps I'll do it like this if all else fails, however, this requires writing a program and setting up a server on a computer. I thought that maybe there is a 5 min solution. Perhaps it's too exotic problem to have a (almost) ready solution. I'll also take a look at Calc macros.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with Powershell:

1. [`Import-Csv`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx) file
2. for each row, construct a string
3. Send that string to the printer using the [`Out-Printer`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849886.aspx) cmdlet

So a script would look something like:

```
Import-Csv .\process.csv | foreach { "Name:$($_.Name)`nPath:$($_.Path)`nProduct:$($_.Product)" | Out-Printer}
```